# How can I share a const char array between two source files gracefully?

Tags: c, c99, c11

To simplify my code, I make the code snippet below to explain my question:

**def.h**

```
#ifndef _DEF_H_
#define _DEF_H_
const char draw[] = "Draw on the canvas:"
#endif
```

**circle.c**

```
#include "def.h"

void draw_circle(void)
{
    printf("%s %s", draw, "a circle.");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "def.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s %s", draw, "nothing.");
}
```

The problem is that there will be no problem at compile-time but it will probably fail on link-time because of the redefinition of const char array, `draw[]`.

How to prevent this problem to share a const char array between two source files gracefully without putting them into a single compilation unit by adding `#include"circle.c"` at the top of `main.c`?

Is it possible?

Comment: Unless you have made a typo, there is no need to include `circle.c` nor `def.c` at the top of `main.c`. Keep `def.h` and create separate compilation unit, named `def.c` as pointed by @YuHao. Don't forget to include `def.h` within `def.c` to avoid risk of declaration/definition mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get multiple definition error when linking because, you put the **definition** of `draw` in a header file. Don't do that. Put only **declarations** in the header, and put **definitions** in one `.c` file.

In you example, put this in a `.c` file

```
const char draw[] = "Draw on the canvas:"
```

And put this in the header:

```
extern const char draw[];
```

Comment: extern const char draw [20]

Comment: Will need to add length of the char array in the header. 
Otherwise you will get error if you try to get length of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no real named constants in C for such types. The only possibility are macros. For strings you could do

```
#define draw "Draw on the canvas:"
```

or if you want to insist that it is `const` qualified:

```
#define draw (char const*)"Draw on the canvas:"
#define draw (char const[]){ "Draw on the canvas:" }
```

The last shows the possibility for other types, use compound literals. Here using `const` is important, such that the compiler may optimize better.